# Directive scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive in angular and a form which is bound to a scope variable. Code:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>

<form>
    <input ng-model="username" required>
</form>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    restrict : 'E',
    controller: function($scope){
        console.log($scope.username); // Displays user name, same scope!!!
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       // Other codes
    },
    templateUrl: "templates/my-template-url.html"
  }
})
```

The username variable can be reached inside the controller in my directive. This is not why I expected since I close the directive and they shouldn't share the same scope?

Why does this work?

Answer (score 5):

Well you are using `scope:false` . It can access and change it's parent scope.

So your node scope doesn't matter here because `username` is in it's parent scope.

```
<my-directive></my-directive>

<form>
    <input ng-model="username" required>
</form>
```

If your don't wanna to access parent scope then create an isolate scope

Like this

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {},
    controller: function($scope){
        console.log($scope.username); // Displays user name, same scope!!!
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       // Other codes
    },
    templateUrl: "templates/my-template-url.html"
  }
})
```